# How to publish (file system) Visual Studio project through TeamCity's MS build?

Tags: visual-studio, build, msbuild, filesystems, teamcity

I am trying to publish a VS project through TeamCity's MS build. I am not sure how to configure the command line parameters (or other configurations) to be able to publish the project and then move the published project to a server.

Current configuration in the MS Build build step:

Runner Type: MSBuild

Execute step: if all prev. steps finished successfully

Build file path: *points to .csproj*

Working directory: none

MSBuild version: MS Build Tools 2013

MSBuild ToolsVersion: 12.0

Targets: Publish

Command Line params: /t:Package /p:_PackageTempDir=”\**path to output**\output” /p:Configuration=”Release” /p:OutputPath=bin\Debug

.NET Coverage tool: none

Answer (score 3):

Change your *Command Line params* to look like this: `/t:Package /p:_PackageTempDir=”\path to output\output” /p:Configuration=”Release” /p:OutputPath=bin\Debug /p:DeployOnBuild=true`
Note the addition of: **/p:DeployOnBuild=true**